# Adding and Displaying Video from a random array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, arrays

I have an iOS app that currently allows the user to tap on an image. A random image from an array, along with a description of the image is then shown to the user. I’d like to add a random video that is an example of the image.

So:
1. User taps image of a photo.
2. A new random photo along with a description is displayed.
3. Specific video about the photo is displayed.

The first two parts (image and description) are working, but I don’t know how to get the video file to display. My tries below:

Html element to hold the video display:

```html
<video id="video_holder">

</video>
```

```js
<!-- This script creates random photos along with descriptions when clicked. I want to add random videos too.  -->
<!-- Begin-->

< script type = "text/javascript" >
  var rand1 = 0;
var useRand = 0;

var descriptions = [];
var videos = [];


var descriptionHolder = document.getElementById('description_holder');//image description
var videoHolder = document.getElementById('video_holder');//add video var



//Starter
function swapPic() { //call a random image when image clicked

  var imgnum = images.length = 37; //Get first 38 of array starts at 0 so subtract 1 to get all elements or number to designate num elements.

  do {
    var randnum = Math.random();

    rand1 = Math.round((imgnum - 1) * randnum) + 1;
  } while (rand1 == useRand);
  useRand = rand1;
  document.randimg.src = images[useRand].src;
  descriptionHolder.innerHTML = descriptions[useRand]; //photo description for first 38 photos
 videoHolder.innerHTML = videos[useRand]; //here is where I'm lost!
}

   

   

images = new Array;
images[1] = new Image();
images[1].src = "images/Photo1.png";
descriptions[1] = “A lovely photo about….”;


images[2] = new Image();
images[2].src = "images/Photo2.png";
descriptions[2] = “Another photo description here…”;;
```

I’ve tried adding another category to my array, but it doesn’t work. Like this:

```js
images[1] = new Image();
images[1].src = "images/Photo4.png";
descriptions[1] = “More words of description here…“;
videos[1] = “videos / myvideo1.mp4”;
```

I’ve also tried this:

```js
images = new Array;
images[1] = new Image();
images[1].src = "images/Photo1.png";
descriptions[1] = “photo description here…”;
videos[1].src = "images/videos/myVideo.mp4";
```

I'm sure those of you who know this stuff are wondering,"What the heck is she doing?" I appreciate your patience. Thank you in advance for your help. I am swimming in the deep end of the pool and need lifepreserver. -Rachel

Comment: HTML ID of video element says "video_Holder", but JS says "video_holder". Need to match. Also... not clear on relationship of 1st image to rest, but if 2nd "random" image, description, and video are all related, you could store them as JS objects instead of in separate arrays. Each as a property of the same object, e.g. `item.image`, `item.description`, `item.video` ... multiple images or videos could be in arrays ... `item.video[1]`. ... If everything is random & unrelated, then disregard :) Last - you set imgnum to images.length (good), but then hard-code it to 37 (don't need to).

Comment: Thank you mc01. I've corrected the mismatch. That was a problem with my entering on stack overflow. I'd like to add the video to my array or image and description.It would show/display with the description and image when called randomly. They are related. I don't know much coding so I need to use what is working for me as the above code does work for the image and photo. I don't know how to get the video to display or add it to my array. Not sure which I need to do. Thank you again for trying to help me.

Comment: mc01- I'm doing a HAPPY DANCE here! Finally, after several days of trying to figure this out, it is working. That is thanks to your explanation. I can't believe that I'm actually beginning to understand a tiny bit of this stuff. :-D It can certainly be a cause for lots of head banging though. Thanks again, Rachel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can add a more detailed answer later, but using `innerHTML` of `videoHolder` will only put the video filename as text inside the `<video>` tag.

```
<video>
   images/videos/myvideo.mp4
</video>
```

As you've discovered, this doesn't work :)

You need to change the `src` attribute of the `videoHolder` element:

```
<video id="video_holder" src="images/videos/myvideo.mp4">
```

OR add a `<source>` node w/the filename instead (this route allows multiple file types: mp4, ogv, webm, etc):

```
<video id="video_holder">
   <source src="images/videos/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="images/videos/myvideo.webm" type="video/webm>
</video>
```

The easiest approach in your JS would be:

```
videoHolder.src = videos[useRand];
```

or

```
videoHolder.innerHTML = "<source src='" + videos[useRand] + "' type='video/mp4'>";
```

(Note, haven't tested this, but should hopefully point you in the right direction)

Comment: mc01: I wonder if you can answer a "why" question for me. When I use `videoHolder.innerHTML = "<source src='" + videos[useRand] + "' type='video/mp4'>";` the first video runs any other random video generates a black screen. (Sure gave me some head scratching for a while) Then I tried the `videoHolder.src = videos[useRand];` and the black screen disappeared. Everything seems to work now. Can you tell me what the problem was with the first code vs the second code? Thank you. -Rachel